# R install package RevoScaleR

Tags: r, install.packages, revolution-r

In trying to install package "RevoScaleR", I get the following error. I have tried installing this package with various versions of R but get the same error every time. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
install.packages("RevoScaleR")
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>     package ‘RevoScaleR’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `RevoScaleR` is a commercial product by Revolution Analytics.  Contact their [sales team](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/contact-us) for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am  not sure what R version you are currently using but the latest stable version is 3.1.2. If the package installation warning is telling that the package you're trying to install is not available, that basically means that the package developer has not yet made a version of the package that is compatible with the R version you're currently running.

If you really need to use this package (if your work heavily depends on it and you are on some kind of deadline) I would advise to install an earlier version of R (like 3.1.1 or 3.1) and do your work with it.

I would also suggest that you reach out to Revolution Analytics, as suggested by Andrie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just to update this post,to install the RevoScaleR package you need to install Microsoft R client, see here for details:

https://www.blue-granite.com/tutorials/sql-server-r-services

R Client includes the ScaleR (rx[…]) functions in the RevoScaleR package. I don't believe this package is open source so isn't available on cran, install.packages() therefore won't work.

Answer (score 3):

The RevoScaleR package is only available if you install the Microsoft R Client or if you use Microsoft RStudio Server via Azure. After you install this you don't need to do install.packages("RevoScaleR") for it is already installed.

R Studio will automatically have the R version [64-bit] C:\Program Files\Microsoft\R Client\R_SERVER under "Global options"

Answer (score 2):

The link below gives more detail information about Microsoft R client. Once you install Ms R client and update the R-studio path to the R client you don't need to install 'RevoScaleR' anymore, it  comes pre-installed with Microsoft R client. Read the link fore more.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/r-client-get-started

Answer (score -1):

You just have to set the propper CRAN repos:

```
options("repos" = c(CRAN = "https://mran.microsoft.com/"))
```

and then

```
install.packages("RevoScaleR")
```

will run properly.