# Microsoft R - No package could not find RevoScaleR?

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I have installed the new "Microsoft R Open 3.4.0" but I can't see the Microsoft R Package e.g. RevoScaleR. Here you can see the following error message. And you can see the sessionInfo, whit the result, that online the Base-R packages are loaded.

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Microsoft R Open 3.4.0
The enhanced R distribution from Microsoft
Microsoft packages Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation

Using the Intel MKL for parallel mathematical computing(using 2 cores).

Default CRAN mirror snapshot taken on 2017-05-01.
See: https://mran.microsoft.com/.

> library(RevoScaleR)
Error in library(RevoScaleR) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘RevoScaleR’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0   RevoUtils_10.0.4 tools_3.4.0
```

Comment: Try installing the Microsoft R client https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/r-client-get-started#installrclient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For using RevoScaleR, you need to install Microsoft R Client, Microsoft R Server.
RevoScaleR can not be downloaded like other OpenSource R packages. It comes inbuilt when you install Microsoft R Client, Microsoft R Server.
Refer [R install package RevoScaleR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999627/r-install-package-revoscaler)

Comment: @user43348044 glad to know that, you may check here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)